# Outlook Inspector Window not consistently closing automatically when triggered via Javascript Mailto code on webpage

Tags: javascript, vba, outlook

I'm attempting to automatically close an Outlook Inspector Window that is automatically opened after clicking on a button that has a Javascript `mailto:` call linked to it (injected). I thought I was using the right Outlook events, but maybe not. What I'm currently doing is subscribing to the `Inspectors_NewInspector` and `Inspector_Activate` events in order to detect when the window opens/becomes visible, then I'm trying to close it from within the `Inspector_Activate` event. The only reason I need the email at all is in order to trigger other VBA code to execute upon the specific button in the web browser being clicked, as well as reading the subject of the email. Since there appear(s/ed) to be no direct way to control Outlook from Javascript that doesn't involve using Internet Explorer (I'm using Chrome) or the Microsoft Office API I came to the conclusion that this is the best way for me to go about it.

**My current problem:**

I can read data from the new email/Inspector window, but can't consistently get the window to close automatically. It'll only close automatically intermittently. Other times I'm left with a frozen Inspector window in which I can only close by clicking the red X of the window. Nothing else is even clickable in the window.

[image: Inspector Window]

**What I've tried:**

I've attempted to place calls to close the window in various spots throughout the code; some errored and others did nothing. I've tried putt `DoEvents` Loops in various spots throughout the code; all waiting for different things to load, but they either had no effect or got stuck in infinite loops. I can't even tell you how many times I've made Outlook crash while trying to figure this out. What's more, is while attempting to debug the issue I receive the same readings for a successful case as I do an unsuccessful case. The first portion below is a successful execution where the code automatically closes the window and the second one the window was still open after the code was done.

Output in Immediate Window:

```
m_Inspectors_NewInspector Event: 1
Beginning m_Inspectors_Activate Event: 1
Closing
Should be closed
End m_Inspectors_Activate Event: 0
------------------------------------------------------
m_Inspectors_NewInspector Event: 1
Beginning m_Inspectors_Activate Event: 1
Closing
Should be closed
End m_Inspectors_Activate Event: 0
------------------------------------------------------
```

**What I currently have:**

Below is my code in the `ThisOutlookSession`:

```
Private WithEvents m_Inspectors As Inspectors
Private WithEvents m_Inspector As Inspector
Private WithEvents Mail As MailItem

Public Sub Initialize_handler()
    Set m_Inspectors = Application.Inspectors
End Sub

Private Sub m_Inspectors_NewInspector(ByVal Inspector As Inspector)
    If TypeOf Inspector.CurrentItem Is Outlook.MailItem Then
        'Handle emails only
        Set m_Inspector = Inspector
        Debug.Print "m_Inspectors_NewInspector Event: " & m_Inspectors.Count
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub m_Inspector_Activate()
    Debug.Print "Beginning m_Inspectors_Activate Event: " & m_Inspectors.Count
    Dim Mail As Object
    DoEvents
    Set Mail = m_Inspector.CurrentItem
    If Mail Is Nothing Then Debug.Print "Mail is Nothing": Exit Sub

    If Mail.To = "velo@automated.com" Then
        Dim clipB As String, DataObj As MsForms.DataObject
        Select Case Mail.Subject
            Case "Import", "Export"
                Set DataObj = New MsForms.DataObject
                DataObj.GetFromClipboard
                clipB = DataObj.GetText(1)
                'MsgBox (IIf(Mail.Subject = "Import", "Import for ", "Export for ") & clipB)
                Mail.Close olDiscard
                Set Mail = Nothing
                'Set m_Inspector = Nothing
            Case Else
                MsgBox ("Hmm")
                Exit Sub
        End Select
    End If
    Debug.Print "End m_Inspectors_Activate Event: " & m_Inspectors.Count
    Debug.Print "------------------------------------------------------"
    Set m_Inspector = Nothing
End Sub

Private Sub Mail_Close(Cancel As Boolean)
    Cancel = False
End Sub

Private Sub m_Inspector_Close()
    'MsgBox ("Close!")
    Debug.Print "Closing"
    'Set m_Inspector = Nothing
    Debug.Print "Should be closed"
End Sub
```

And for sake of completeness, here is the relevant part of my injected Javascript code:

```
$(document).on('click', 'button.btn-large:nth-child(3)', function(){
    var fullsupplier;
    fullsupplier = document.getElementById("asinum").innerHTML + " " + document.getElementById("supplierName").innerHTML;
    //alert(fullsupplier);
    copyTextToClipboard(fullsupplier);
    window.location.href = "mailto:velo@automated.com?subject=Import";
});

$(document).on('click', 'button.btn-large:nth-child(1)', function(){
    var fullsupplier;
    fullsupplier = document.getElementById("asinum").innerHTML + " " + document.getElementById("supplierName").innerHTML;
    //alert(fullsupplier);
    copyTextToClipboard(fullsupplier);
    window.location.href = "mailto:velo@automated.com?subject=Export";
});
```

**My Question:**

What am I doing wrong? How can I make the Inspector Window *always* close automatically instead of intermittently?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that emails that are created from an external process (eg. mailto: links, send from Word, etc.) do not fire the NewInspector event.  You'll have to use a timer to detect when Inspectors.Count change and set a hook into the newly added Inspector.  Then you can trap its events.

Comment: Your first statement can't be true because I've had a message box fire in that event when testing this. Are you saying that it won't *consistently/reliably* fire? That would make a lot of sense as to why I'd be having this issue then. Could you help me out with an example of what you're talking about doing?

Comment: Correction: it looks like mailto: links AND sending from Word does fire the event.  But right-clicking a file and choosing Send To -> Mail recipient does not fire the event (that uses the SendMail.dll, which breaks a lot of things; which Word use to use). Otherwise the event should always fire. However, I seem to recall that closing an Inspector during the Activate event may be problematic.  A timer could still be a workaround.

Comment: how or where would I implement a timer for this situation though? In what event? Can you provide an example?

Comment: You can declare a System.Windows.Forms.Timer object in your current class and handle the Tick event.  Create the object variable at the point when your class is created or any other time you want (maybe in Initialize_handler).  Set the Interval to 60000 to check every minute or less

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Eric's answer, you also need to make sure that you have a list of inspectors and hence mail items - there can be more than one item open at the same time.